# continuous line drawing in QT

Tags: qt

I need to draw line continuously on the screen, output should be as it is in the video. Please check this link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sYNIm210mJY.

Please suggest me which is the best method to implement it.

Answer (score 3):

Please check the [scribble](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/widgets-scribble.html) example (located in `Qt examples/widgets/scribble/`) provided by Qt.

You'll find everything you need to get what you want !

Comment: The line should be drawn Programmatically. there is no mouse down and other mouse events..

Comment: That example code is still a good resource. Most of it applies to your objective. Just replace the mouse driven code with a timer event that generates new random coordinates.